# Unable to open connection using a "using var parameterized queries"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this scenario:

> I have a table called "Entradas" and one called "Saidas". Both have
>   the column "data" and "hora". With that in mind, since the "data" and
>   "hora column of "entradas" mean that a car joined at that date and
>   time, and the values from the columns "data" and "hora" of "saidas"
>   are mean to be inserted as i click a button, inserting the current
>   date and time. I'm requesting a sql syntax that could insert the
>   values "data" and "hora" into the table "saidas" and update a value of
>   "entradas" called "sai" which is equal to 0 and i want it to change to
>   1 on button press.

And i have this procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `entradas_sai`(
IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _rollback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET _rollback = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(date(now()) ,time(now()));
    UPDATE ENTRADAS SET SAI=1;
    IF '_rollback' THEN
        SET retcode = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET retcode = 1;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END
```

And this is my actual code to run it on button click:

```
private void cmdSaida_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=portaria;allowuservariables=True"))
            {
                cn.Open();

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(); 
                    cmd.CommandText = "entradas_sai";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_veiculo", Grid1.SelectedCells[1].Selected);
                    cmd.Parameters["@id_veiculo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retcode", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters["@retcode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var res = cmd.Parameters["@retcode"].Value;

                cn.Close();
             }              
        }
```

And my problem at the moment is that when i click the button, it doesn't execute my procedure neither my commands to open or close the connection. Any sugestions?

EDIT: After some research i found that my actual procedure sets all the values from 0 to 1 in column "sai" how can i do it so it only change the selected grid row value, based on "ID_Entrada"

Comment: Do you get any error/exception message?

Comment: What happens as you trace through it?

Comment: The only thing that visual studio says me its that the connection must be oppened before executing any sql features... But i open it up, as it goes, and on breakpoint debug, it passes to that spot on the cn.Open(); and closes the string, disabling all the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `MySqlCommand` object, but it's not associated with any connection.  There has to be an active connection in order to execute a command.

You can associate it on the constructor:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("entradas_sai", cn);
```

or after the constructor:

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
```